# Firebase Security: Only users who are referenced in the object should read it

Tags: security, firebase, backend, rules

I have objects in my Firebase and I want to restrict access only to **users who are referenced in the object**. My Firebase structure looks like this:

- Object

  - object_info
  - contacts

    - $contact_id

      - user_id
      - user_role
- users

  - $user_id

    - user_info

object/contacts/$contact_id/user_id references to users/$user_id

So every user who should have access appears as **user_id** in one child of **contacts**. Unfortunately I cannot find a method to search all children of **contacts** for a certain **user_id**.
Is there a way to set this Firebase security rule of should I change my whole Database Structure in order to keep it safe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check for the existence of the user's node:

```
{
  "Object": {
    ".read": "data.child('contacts').child(auth.uid).exists()"
  }
}
```

Comment: unfortunately, I can not. the child data.child('contacts').child(auth.uid) will never exist. The users key in auth.uid is stored one layer deeper in a contact that stores more information than the user key. This is because I need to work with contacts that aren't registered yet, and when they register I can just update the reference to the user without having to update everything associated to this contact.

Comment: In that case it won't work and you'll need to change your data model to allow the use-case you're trying to implement.

Comment: Thanks! Any recommendations how to achieve this? The problem is that if I directly reference to the user, I will have to search everything associated to this object and check if the contact appears somewhere to update the contact's key.

Comment: You'll need to have a key in a known location so that you can use `exists()`, like in my snippet. So add an inverted data structure to your current approach: a list of users that can access the object.

Comment: Alright, however there is one more thing. I want to display a list of all objects (my object here is a child of objects) that are available for one user. But if I specify my firebase rule so that every user who has access to $object can read it, I cannot read the parent **objects** anymore which I need to display the available list without knowing the object keys. (I use Angularfire and want to display my objects using ng-repeat="objects in object")

Comment: You'll need to split the parent objects and child objects into separate top-level nodes. One contains the public information that everyone can see, the other contains the private/secured information.